# How to make a part of the fancy box transparent?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

I tried using fancybox instead of lightbox since I wanted to put a text over an image. I'm not quite familiar with lighboxes/fancyboxes but I tried to look inside the code and tweaked a bit to see if it affects the opacity of what i wanted to make transparent. But unfortunately, I can't seem to change it. Is it possible to make the background of the text (the transparent black one) transparent?

Comment: css opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40), but want transparency inside fancybox

Comment: Take a look at [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/logging) and/or [Chrome Console](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html), which would allow you to figure out how to select and style your element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#fancybox-title-over
{
    background:transparent;
}
```

that'll do it.

Comment: I got confused where to change and it turned out that there are 2 css files inside the demo. I already changed it. Thank you sir!

Comment: ah. If you include this in your own style sheet on the page, it will cascade overriding any previous declarations.  Also, firebug is a must have. :)

Comment: I'm using Safari though. Is there also an application for Safari that is the same as Firebug?

Comment: @strawberrymuffin Absolutely.  Most modern browsers come with some kind of development tools and it looks like safari has the same ones that chrome has.  You can enable it (at least in windows) by going to Preferences->Advanced->Show Develop In Menu Bar.  Then just right-click on an element on the page and click "inspect element".